# flywaydb: How to stop accidently clean

Tags: flyway

Inside Flyway Db there is a command called 'clean' if we use that it will drop all the objects in the schema.

Drops all objects (tables, views, procedures, triggers, ...) in the configured schemas.
The schemas are cleaned in the order specified by the schemas property.

How we can disable this so that no one accidentally use it until required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option from the command line, is to wrap Flyway's script with your own. You can then intercept the clean command and no-op it.

Comment: The route I would go down. I'd prefer to not concede control of my build to my database as Chaya's answer points out (single point of truth people). A wrapper script could be combined with a bit of configuration such as a list of dev, test, staging (clean allowed) and production (clean not allowed) schemas.

Comment: Flyway has a cleanDisabled option: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/clean

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do that is to manage privileges on your database and refuse drop operation to the flyway user.

If you do not have the hand on your database configuration and using java Api, you can write an Aspect to throw an exception with an Around advisor on the following pointcut "execution(public * org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.clean(..)" (not tested)

Comment: But I am working only from the default command line, is there a way from there and I can see many errors executing merge statement as compare to normal AQT execution as that works fine there....

Comment: So the only way is to manage the privileges of your database's user in order to refuse the drop instruction.

Answer (score 1):

jrf's comment is more useful, adding this as an answer.

You can have different ***flyway.conf*** file for different environment and set ***flyway.cleanDisabled= true/false***.

Use flyway command with configuration file option:
 example > `flyway -configFile=path/to/myAlternativeConfig.conf clean`  
Now, this should allow you to have separation and flexibility of using clean. Like you can enable clean on dev environment and disable it on prod.

Answer (score 0):

In the 4.0 version  you can disable clean by setting cleanDisabled flag.

In pom

```
 <cleanDisabled>false</cleanDisabled>
```

Refer to
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/clean

https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/458